Can't import svg as React component in Webpack 5 with Single SPA
I have an Single SPA app based on React with Webpack 5.
Importing it in my component:
import SVG from '../assets/some.svg;
<div>
    <SVG/>
</div>

My webpack settings look like this:
rules: [
      test: /\.svg$/i,
      issuer: /\.[jt]sx?$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
]

Having this error:
Image of the error
I tried different using url loader and file-loader didn't work.

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.. And also share the actual error, not only where it throws.
